# Can all weapon types mount?

Tags: monster-hunter-world

In Monster Hunter World can all weapon types do a jumping mount attack? I've been toggling back and forth between gun lance and twin blades and I don't seem to be able to mount with gunlance which I guess would make sense given the way the weapon works but it would be handy?  I'm also not beyond thinking its just bad timing/luck on my end.

Comment: Interesting tidbit, when using a switch axe, the upward swing will launch any player it hits up into the air in an arch away from you.  Yesterday I was able to use this to launch one of my friends into the air where they started a mounting.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, every weapon can mount and has special attacks while mounted (the gunlance for example stabs the monster and then does a full burst).

That said, not every weapon type can just jump and perform a mounting attack and you need to use the environment to get airborne in order to perform mount attacks.

Everyone can jump off ledges, use slopes, wallvines, climbing vines, and even other players (greatsword launching attack) to get up in the air for mounting attacks.

There are also armor skills and charms that can help with mounting (instead of landing 3 mounting attacks, you only need 1 for example). Check with the smithy on which armor piece has this skill

I haven't used it, but there is also a mantle that apparently really helps with mounting as well.

Personal anecdote: I main gunlance and almost always get the most mounts per hunt(unless there is an Insect glaive user in my group)

Comment: Can any ranged weapons mount? I dont use them personally too much, just curious.

Comment: They sure can, probably the most difficult ones to do so... but they are definitely capable.

Comment: interesting I had just assumed that they couldn't which was making me avoid them thanks again for the awesome reply @Rapitor

Answer (score 10):

Yes! Every weapon is capable of mounting a monster, however not every weapon has a standalone jumping attack (required to mount the monster).

Still every weapon is capable of doing a mounting attack when either:

- Jumping off a ledge / wall
- Sliding and connecting into a jump attack.

Whenever you perform an aerial attack on a monster you will do "mounting damage". Once a certain amount of mounting damage is dealt you will automatically mount a monster.

Note that it's "easier" for certain weapons to reach the mounting damage threshold. A Greatsword might only require 1-2 jumping attacks in order to mount the monster (since it deals way more damage per hit) while it might need 3-5 jumping attacks with dual blades.

Also there are some weapons that can do standalone jumping attacks (Lance or Insect Glaive for example).

Comment: Thanks for the great reply I had tried a few times with the Gunlance but it wasnt really working so I was beginning to assume that it wasn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in other answers, every weapon (*even a bow and a bowgun*) is capable of performing jump attack and/or sliding attack.

However, some are capable of jumping out of nowhere to mount even on unfriendly terrain, and here is the exhaustive list.

- **Sword and Shield** can perform Jumping Slash as a combo from Charged Slash. Note that Falling Bash does not allow you to mount.
- **Lance** can jump out of its lance charge and perform an aerial thrust as a jump attack.
- **Insect Glaive**, of course, has its vault and falling attack.
- **Bow** (yes, BOW) can Charge Step-forward and thrust with its arrow. Although the jump height is too low to pull off unassisted mounting under normal circumstances, monsters with low height (e.g., Tobi-Kadachi) or sloped terrain will grant mounting.

Also, keep in mind that there are some aerial attacks which might seem as mounting attacks, but actually aren't. For example, Spirit Helm Breaker of a Longsword will not contribute to mounting at all.